# Postgres 10 cluster not starting up

Tags: linux, postgresql, package

**I post this error for those people who also faced a similar problem**

LOG: Can't exec "": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 211.

This error appeared after updating the openssl package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of swimming in the logs it was found out that there is a problem in the dependencies between packages **postgresql** and **openssl**

```
 apt-get install postgresql-all
```

Resolving my problem

Comment: Would help if the OS and version where specified as well as the package repo used. Also how was openssl package updated and from what version to what version?